# A warning to the wise - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> I begin with deception in the way that I act
>   Then grow in obsession with only the facts.
>   I sometimes yell loudly and sometimes I whisper
>   Some things may confound me but don't let me wither
>   For if I'm neglected in present or past
>   Your life is affected and peace may not last

What am I?

Hint

> My first two lines are wordplay. The rest of the lines validate what I am by my characteristics.
>  In addition to the word play lines:
>  I'm an artist and a fake: this is true as my first
>  Then I ask bio or physics: which one's the worst?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're after

> **Conscience**

I begin with deception in the way that I act

> The first part of the word is 'con', a lie. This is elaborated upon in your hint (see below).

Then grow in obsession with only the facts.

> The second part of the word is 'science', the pursuit of facts. (Also elaborated upon in your hint.)

I sometimes yell loudly and sometimes I whisper
Some things may confound me but don't let me wither
For if I'm neglected in present or past
Your life is affected and peace may not last

> These describe the actual meaning of the word. Our conscience might merely nag us at times, and outright torment us at other times ('yell loudly' and 'whisper'). And a lack of conscience will make us all ruthless, severely harming the world.

I'm an artist and a fake: this is true as my first

> This further explains the first line; a *con-artist* uses fakery and deception.

Then I ask bio or physics: which one's the worst?

> This adds to the second line; both are sciences. As for which is the worst, don't look at me. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are:

> History (But I hope your intended answer is better, just felt this could fit)

I begin with deception in the way that I act

> Historical information can be deceiving, E.g facts about money inflation, climate change, etc. All can lead to a false sense of security.

Then grow in obsession with only the facts

> Some people only obsess over the facts from history but personal accounts and other stories are also important.

I sometimes yell loudly and sometimes I whisper

> Some moments in history are more important than others but things are still recorded. Could also be referencing historical protests both loud and silent ones.

Some things may confound me but don't let me wither

> Some things or people may try to erase or tarnish history, but it's important to not let that happen.

For if I'm neglected in present or past

> "History repeats itself" - Many people, historians, survivors, etc.

Your life is affected and peace may not last

> Ignoring past mistakes could lead to things like war, E.g not learning from the World Wars etc.

Comment: +1 nice guess, but not the correct answer. I think your explanation for some lines work quite well, but for others, it seems like more of a stretch. I too, hope that my intended answer fits more snugly

Answer (score 0):

I think you're:

> Gamble

I begin with deception in the way that I act

> poker face

Then grow in obsession with only the facts

> Addiction to gambling

I sometimes yell loudly and sometimes I whisper

> That's what you'll do when gambling

Some things may confound me but don't let me wither

> Losing (or winning) big once a while confound you but won't stop you from gambling

For if I'm neglected in present or past

> Gambling exists in present / past but it's 'effect' is neglected

Your life is affected and peace may not last

> Sure does

Comment: nice try, but I think beyond the first line, the connections seem fairly loose

Answer (score 0):

> Financial markets.

I begin with deception in the way that I act

> It can make you think that you know how it works and you can predict it but soon such beliefs are shattered.

Then grow in obsession with only the facts

> It grows or decays with factual information.

I sometimes yell loudly and sometimes I whisper

> It moves wildly (momentum)in certain phases and in certain phases it remains silent (low volatility or range bound).

Some things may confound me but don't let me wither

> Sometimes markets becomes inefficient and moves away from its true value for example Indian markets opening 3% down on Brexit but it again swung back up.

For if I'm neglected in present or past

> If fundamental process of historical mistakes such as IT bubble , Subprime mortgage crisis (2008) is ignored and repeated again ....

Your life is affected and peace may not last

> It could push several economies into depression etc.